# Row count function always returns NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created an SQL function that implements an faster alternative  to the `COUNT(*)` operation:

```
create function fast_row_count (@table_name varchar)
returns bigint 
as 
begin
declare @row_count int; 
set @row_count = 
(select sum(row_count) from sys.dm_db_partition_stats with (nolock) where object_id = object_id(@table_name));
return @row_count
end
go
```

When executing, it always returns a NULL value.

```
select dbo.fast_row_count('tbl_calls')
```

However, when executing  as a separate batch with a hardcoded value , it works correctly:

```
    declare @row_count int;
    set @row_count = 
    (select sum(row_count) from sys.dm_db_partition_stats with (nolock) where object_id = object_id('tbl_calls'));
    print  @row_count
```

Comment: `varchar` without a length? That's a no-no. Try `SYSNAME`.

Comment: `varchar` without length is just `varchar(1)`. Your table name probably doesn't fit in one character, does it?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: declare varchar(MAX) or 100

Comment: This was it. It works with @table_name as `SYSNAME` or `varchar(n)`.

Comment: So SQL Server automatically assigns a size 1 to a `varchar` data type. Is that it?

Comment: Not quite, sometimes it's 30. (Sounded like a good number, I guess.) Read the link @GarethD provided. Basically, you always want to supply a length and avoid that mess.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you will get an incorrect count if the table you are trying to count the rows of has an index on, you need to limit the sum to just the heap (0) and clustered (1) indexes: `WHERE index_id IN (0, 1)`

Comment: I've had a need for doing this in a database that involved queues (both table-based and Service Broker). See http://pastebin.com/DHxT37WZ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create function fast_row_count (@table_name varchar (max))
```

due to you are defining varchar and not defining its lenght so its giving null

**varchar [ ( n | max ) ]**

> Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.

**Remarks**

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

for more information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176089.aspx